# CakePHP How to block IP address which access to Login page except my own IP address

Tags: cakephp

Assume I have a login page (http://www.my-website.com/login/) and I want to block all users which access to login page base on their IP address except my own IP address. Could you help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your controller:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->clientIp() != 'Your IP address here') {
        throw new ForbiddenException();
    }

    ...
}
```